# Formatting results from printing an array (PHP and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php
include('settings.php'); //Here I have my connection string

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT myrow FROM mytable");
   $storeArray = Array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $storeArray[] =  $row['myrow'];  
   }

   print_r($storeArray);

?>
```

And the results look like this:
Array ( [0] => emailaddress1@email.com [1] => [2] => emailaddress2@email.com [3] => emailaddress3@email.com )

I was wondering what I need to do in order for it to print like this:

emailaddress1@email.com, emailaddress2@email.com, emailaddress3@email.com ..and so forth.

The reason is I've been tasked with creating mailing list, so I need to print out all of the email addresses in the database in an easy-to-insert into Outlook format

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)`( ', ', $storeArray)`

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I asked.

Comment: @mario this was one of the questions when the answer is link to the manual :-/ there are examples on php.net, lot's of comments... I don't see the point in detail description when all he needed was function name (we all have been there when we were stuck with something which was handled by single function and we didn't know). Anyway if you have anything that could make my answer better I'll be glad to edit and extend (but **this** time it just feels right for me).

Answer (score 1):

Or try this method :

```
foreach($storeArray as $value)
    $stringval.= $value.', ';

$finalval = substr($stringval,0,-2);
echo $finalval;
```

Comment: This would result into: `a@b.c, d@e.f, g@h.i, ` so he would have to deal with trailing coma and space.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Dinu. I believe the solution Vyktor is the simplest (and in this case best) solution. Still, thanks for your work.

Comment: Yes, it's correct now. Or you could have used `rtrim( ', ', $stringval)`. Or maybe: `$stringval = array_shift( $storeArray); foreach(){ $stringval .= ', ' . $value}`, but generally, `implode` is quickest, most effective and most readable way to do this (except special cases with large amount of data).